# How to replace or strip the [number] from string with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The value of `selected` variable is "Topic [9]" or "Category [10]". i want to remove "[number]" from the value of `selected` variable?

```
selected = $('#topic_id option:selected').text();
```

i think, i can strip value with `replace()` as follows but need to know, how do i achieve because number is not fixed.

```
selected = $('#topic_id option:selected').text().replace();
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to do this, but you need to provide more info, if it is always going to be one word and then a number, you can split() and take the first part, or you can detach after the word.

Comment: You could just find the index of the "[", and remove all the characters that follow.  Something like (and I know this syntax isn't correct)  newVal = left(string,indexOf(string."["))  Should give you all the characters to the left of where that bracket appears.

Comment: I think @DontVoteMeDown has the good approach. Thank you for taking time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with jQuery but with pure [Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). Just use regex, like this one `\[.+` to do it.

```
selected = $('#topic_id option:selected').text().replace(/\[.+/g, "");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nzD9c/1/).

Of course this only works on the pattern you have provided: With `[number]` at the end of the string.

**UPDATE**: As @Zack pointed on the comments, you can use this regex `\s\[.+` to remove the space before the `[`.

Comment: Regex is going way to far, your making it for more complicated then it needs to be.

Comment: @Ohjay44 WTF? I think you would propose `split()`? Come on! hahaha

Comment: @Ohjay44 That's a ridiculous oversimplification. Using a _simple_ regex does not complicate anything unless you don't know how to use them.

Comment: If he had one word, which he didn't specify, then yes he could split and then he would have it. Regex is much more complicated for such a simple thing as cutting of the end.

Comment: Your regex replace will just remove everything after the first `[` right? Wouldn't you need to remove the space before it as well? `.replace(/\s\[.+/g, "");`

Comment: yeah, value could have more than one word.

Comment: Thank you @Zack, i was about to ask this.

Comment: @Ohjay44 it is complicated only for your limited knowledge, and I think you are the only one around here.

Comment: hey guys, plz dont forget to upvote the question, i dont know why i get downvotes. :)

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown is it my limited knowledge, or your closed mind to the other possibilities? I would be right in saying that there are a number of ways to do one thing when programming, there are easier ways, and complicated ways. So maybe it's that your to comfortable doing something one way that you can't accept the possibility that there is a much simpler way. If it were only one word he needed then yes split() would have been quick. Now that I know he might have more then one, then yes Regex works best, but it is still not the only way.

Comment: @Ohjay44 look at zack's answer following your proposal. He's using three commands `split`, `pop` and `join` to achieve what you can do in one line in one command. Which one is more complicated for somebody who is learning a language? Further, think about performance of three commands agains one. Yes, there is many ways to do one thing in programming, but exists the good way and the extreme go horse way, which you do what first cames to your mind. You mind is close since you down-voted me because you though your way was better, not considering mine worked for the OP too.

Answer (score 3):

Ohjay44 was onto something with the split, but didn't provide an answer, so I went ahead.
This solution will split the `selected` string by the space character, then call `pop()` which removes the last element of the array, then it uses `join(" ")` which returns the elements of an array as a string, concatenated with the provided seperator, or `,` if none is provided.

Here is a working example on jsfiddle.net http://jsfiddle.net/jX36T/

```
var selected = "Topic of conversation [9]";
var splitted = selected.split(" ");
splitted.pop();
var string = splitted.join(" ");
alert(stringResult);
```

Displays "Topic of conversation"

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one word to get, you can explode with the space character and keep the first item of the returned array

Comment: but value can have more than one word

Comment: .split(' ') (not explode) If more than one word, you can get all the items of the array, but not the last one